# Terraform Get Previous Version Of Vault Secret

Tags: terraform, vault

Is it programmatically possible to access the previous version of a Vault secret in Terraform using the vault_generic_secret resouce?

If the current version of a Vault secret is 21, Terraform datasource can access the previous secret version like so:

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "ssh_key_previous_version" {
  path = "kv/dev/ssh/var.ssh_key_name"
  version = 20
}
```

Is there a process to lookup the previous Vault secret version (key version -1) dynamically ?

Comment: I do not see that in the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/data-sources/generic_secret ...

you can try see if that is even possible using the vault api, IF it is, you will need to modify the terraform provider to add that feature

Answer (score 0):

The `vault_generic_secret` data source was originally written for much earlier versions of Vault, before the Key/Value backend supported versioning.

However, current versions of the `hashicorp/vault` provider also support [`vault_kv_secret_v2`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs/data-sources/kv_secret_v2), which is a data source designed specifically for version 2 of the key/value store API in Vault.

```
data "vault_kv_secret_v2" "ssh_key_previous_version" {
  mount   = "kv"
  name    = "dev/ssh/${var.ssh_key_name}"
  version = 20
}
```

(Notice that if you want to refer to `var.ssh_key_name` as part of a string you will need to use the string interpolation syntax `${ ... }`, or else Terraform will take `var.ssh_key_name` literally. I assumed that you intended to refer to a Terraform input variable named `ssh_key_name` there, but if I assumed incorrectly then you can keep the literal string you had in your example.)